# Listing files/directories in Resources/Assets folder in cocos2dx

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x, file-handling

I want to list folders and files inside Resources folder from android and ios. I've been able to do so by 'opendir' and 'readdir' from 'dirent.h' but only in ios emulator. It doesn't work in android.
Did anyone face such problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to mantain a file containing a list of all the files in the resource directory along with their hierarchy.

For example, say you have a directory hirearchy as:

```
Resources/
    folder1/
        file1.jpeg
        file2.jpeg
    folder2/
        file1.jpeg
        file2.jpeg
```

Then you can mantain a file containing the paths as:

```
in resource_paths.txt

folder1/file1.jpeg
folder1/file2.jpeg
folder2/file1.jpeg
folder2/file2.jpeg
```

Then search in the file for list of directories/files :)

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, this can't be done on Android using only C++. Since you already have the iOS part figured out, you shuould wrap the iOS specific code (`#include`s too) in

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
...
#endif
```

The same will aply for Android only code (`CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID') - to achieve what you want you have to write a JNI call in order to call a Java function from C++. Assuming that you want to just dump this data to a log, everything should be pretty straightforward. I don't have a link at hand, but there was an extensive topic about opening URLs which coverd the JNI tutorial and it shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to make JNI call if possible. Let me know if you have any link in hand.